# Can I know in real time when ether is coming into my account from Ethereum?

Tags: nodejs, websocket

I would like to create a feature in my Dapp(nodejs) that notifies me when ether is coming into my account in **real time**.

For example, is there a way to use websockets or APIs?

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Unfortunately unlike ERC-20 deposits, ETH deposits do not generate any event and you cannot get notification on these from a normal JSON-RPC node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options for this. An easy one is to use `web3.eth.subscribe("pendingTransactions",callback)` to listen for incoming transactions that reach the mempool. Then, you can filter by the account/address that you are interested using `tx.to === myAccountAddress`:

To try out this, I used a QuickNode (https://www.quicknode.com/) node, connected to the Rinkeby testnet network and it works fine:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const url =
  "wss://divine-shy-silence.rinkeby.discover.quiknode.pro/<your quicknode rinkeby api key>/";

const options = {
  timeout: 30000,
  clientConfig: {
    maxReceivedFrameSize: 100000000,
    maxReceivedMessageSize: 100000000,
  },
  reconnect: {
    auto: true,
    delay: 5000,
    maxAttempts: 15,
    onTimeout: false,
  },
};

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(url, options));
const subscription = web3.eth.subscribe("pendingTransactions", (err, res) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);
});

const account1 = "0x6827b8f6cc60497d9bf5210d602C0EcaFDF7C405"; // Your test address 1
const account2 = "0x66B0b1d2930059407DcC30F1A2305435fc37315E"; // A second test address

const init = function () {
  subscription.on("data", (txHash) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
        if (tx.to === account1) {
            
          console.log("Receiving some eth for account 1: ", tx);
        } else if (tx.to === account2) {
          console.log("Receiving some eth for account 2: ", tx);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  });
};

init();
```

That would print something like the following every time one of my addresses is receiving some ether:

```js
{
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  from: '0x6827b8f6cc60497d9bf5210d602C0EcaFDF7C405',
  gas: 21000,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: '1500000000',
  maxFeePerGas: '1500000013',
  hash: '0x63dd06e925447df905bbd7d594354fb9c354874dc924f2e52a7d45d0c647787a',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 98,
  to: '0x66B0b1d2930059407DcC30F1A2305435fc37315E',
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: '5310000000000000',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  chainId: '0x4',
  v: '0x1',
  r: '0x1ecc9d1f58656771dccad5291a509a66224d5d8055ff2d705a77b7c8cc5c99fd',
  s: '0x39d71a67319c6f279f913b47b93f9e6acd3128d49ce762f33daeb24b95d3bcfe'
}
```

Note that the transactions will be in the mempool and not confirmed yet in a block, because we are subscribed to `pendingTransactions`, but at least you know that is coming. After that you can try to query it by its transaction hash to see if it's already in a block.
Notice how in the tx above there is no value for `blockHash` or `blockNumber`.

What we can do afterwards, is to try to get the tx again with `web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash):` to see if it's already in a block, and after it is confirmed, the tx should look like this:

```js
{
  blockHash: '0x6f860b5f62096cceb523c077be35f7517d7752a713992573d789a7319863a617',
  blockNumber: 11156860,
  from: '0x6827b8f6cc60497d9bf5210d602C0EcaFDF7C405',
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: '1500000009',
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: '1500000000',
  maxFeePerGas: '1500000013',
  hash: '0x63dd06e925447df905bbd7d594354fb9c354874dc924f2e52a7d45d0c647787a',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 98,
  to: '0x66B0b1d2930059407DcC30F1A2305435fc37315E',
  transactionIndex: 11,
  value: '5310000000000000',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  chainId: '0x4',
  v: '0x1',
  r: '0x1ecc9d1f58656771dccad5291a509a66224d5d8055ff2d705a77b7c8cc5c99fd',
  s: '0x39d71a67319c6f279f913b47b93f9e6acd3128d49ce762f33daeb24b95d3bcfe'
}
```

You can read this article that shows you how to do it: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/defi/how-to-access-ethereum-mempool

Another option would be to run your own testnet/mainnet Ethereum node and use the Geth client to query it. But this is more tedious to set up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by using RPC URLs, and you can interact with ABI to get informations like that.